# Использование AppBar в проекте

Tags: android

Необходим совет best - practics использования appBar.

Как его лучше использовать, один на весь проект (внедрение к layout в main_activity), или же внедрять его в каждый из Fragment-ов?

Хочу использовать AppBarLayout из Material Design для создания гибких и красивых интерфейсов, когда например окно пользователя при скроллинке потом перемещается в Toolbar в виде картинки.

В этом случае как я понимаю нужно использовать контейнер CoordinatorLayout вместе с AppBarLayout, в котором toolbar и NestedScrollView, т.е получается использовать для нужных layout отдельный appbar

C другой стороны использования отдельных appBar не позволяется использовать их в Navigation Library, в котором appBar будет меняться автоматически в зависимости от экрана, на котором мы сейчас находимся, меняя названия и стрелку назад.

Как лучше использовать appbar и можно ли совместить эти 2 подхода?